# Custom comments template in wp theme

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to make a custom comments template for my WordPress theme. I made a copy of the original comments template and put it in my theme folder. Then I changed the

```
<?php comments_template(); ?>
```

to

```
<?php comments_template( '/custom-comments.php'); ?>
```

Just like the codex says. But when I use the custom comments template it doesn't show up and everything after that line in the code disappears.

Is there something I've missed?

My full code:

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="col content">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

            <p class="desc"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author() ?></p>

            <div class="entry">

                <?php the_content(); ?>

                <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => 'Pages: ', 'next_or_number' => 'number')); ?>

                <p class="desc"><?php the_tags( 'Tags: ', ', ', ''); ?></p>

            </div>

            <!--<?php edit_post_link('Edit this entry','','.'); ?>-->

        </div>

    <?php comments_template( '/custom-comments.php'); ?>

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

</div>

<div class="col sidebar">

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: I hate to ask, but is your comments file named "custom_comments.php"? Also, is the file in the root of your theme folder, or in a subdirectory?

Comment: Yes that's its name, and yes it is in the root of my theme folder.

Comment: Which template are you calling the function in?

Comment: I am calling it in single.php

Comment: Can you include the surrounding few lines of code in your question (before and after)? Your usage is correct, with the information that has been given.

Comment: There could also be some kind of syntax error in the custom comments template itself.

Comment: Not at the moment as I'm afk. Maybe I should add that I'm only testing it locally with mamp, if that makes any difference..

Comment: No I haven't changed anything in it. It is identical to the original. Maybe there's a reference to some file which is now wrong?

Comment: Please include the lines of code before and after your `comments_template( '/custom_comments.php');` call.

Comment: They are the same whether I use the original template (which works) or the custom one. could it matter anyway? I'll include them as soon as I can.

Comment: added my full code of single.php

Comment: How about the code in your *custom_comments.php*?

Comment: it's identical to the original.

Answer (score -1):

If you just copy the original *comments-template.php* it contains

Thus tries to redeclare the same php functions.

That creates a fatal error and aborts the processing as the template is included.